# Publishing of pages and component getting stuck at different stages

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

After upgrade from Tridion 5.3 to Tridion 2011 SP1 we are publishing lot of Pages and Component again (as we converted existing Component Templates and Page Templates to Compound Templates.  While publishing few Pages and Components are getting stuck in queue under "Ready for Transport" or "Transporting" or "Waiting for deployment" state and finally getting failed with different errors different times

1) Transport failed: Could not transport tcm_0-277383-66560.Content.zip using HTTPS
2) Polling for notification for destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q== has exceeded polling attempts for transaction: tcm:0-277361-66560

Any thoughts to resolve this, we have 1 thread for publishing and rendering.  Database is SQL Server, Using HTTPUpload.aspx for upload.

CD_Transport.log

```
2012-12-05 05:50:39,302 DEBUG TransportService - Starting handing of a transaction
2012-12-05 05:50:39,302 INFO  TransactionProcessor - No existing transport transaction information for: tcm:0-277451-66560 creating new transaction state
2012-12-05 05:50:39,317 DEBUG TransactionHeader - Writing[TransactionHeader transactionId=tcm:0-277451-66560 control=WAIT] to C:\temp\tcm_0-277451-66560.Content\transaction.xml
2012-12-05 05:50:39,317 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2012-12-05 05:50:39,333 INFO  TransportService - Starting transport handling of transaction: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:39,333 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2012-12-05 05:50:39,333 INFO  TransportPoolManager - Creating a new TransportPoolConnector, because no available connectors in connection pool
2012-12-05 05:50:39,333 DEBUG TransportPoolConnector - Configuring TransportPoolConnector.
2012-12-05 05:50:39,333 DEBUG HTTPSTransportConnector - Authentication information supplied, setting basic credentials
2012-12-05 05:50:39,333 DEBUG DestinationProgressWorker - Starting retrieving active transactions at destination: bNZqVt3QAt1olhLc6Hdaqw==
2012-12-05 05:50:39,364 DEBUG DestinationProgressWorker - Found 0 transactions in progress and 0 waiting transactions.
2012-12-05 05:50:39,364 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.51.151:8082/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2012-12-05 05:50:39,364 INFO  DestinationController - Transaction fits inside current window, proceeding transaction: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:39,364 DEBUG TransactionManager - Destination is available for transport: bNZqVt3QAt1olhLc6Hdaqw==
2012-12-05 05:50:39,364 DEBUG TransactionManager - All destinations are available for transport of transaction: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:39,364 INFO  ZipWorker - Preparing TransportPackage for id: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:39,364 DEBUG ZipWorker - Zipping Transportpackage: c:\Temp\tcm_0-277451-66560.Content
2012-12-05 05:50:44,746 INFO  ZipWorker - Creating rollback and commit packages for transaction: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:44,762 DEBUG TransactionHeader - Writing[TransactionHeader transactionId=tcm:0-277451-66560 control=PREPARE] to D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-277451-66560.PREPARE\transaction.xml
2012-12-05 05:50:44,777 DEBUG ZipWorker - Create Prepare package for transacton: tcm:0-277451-66560 at D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-277451-66560.PREPARE.zip
2012-12-05 05:50:44,777 DEBUG TransactionHeader - Writing[TransactionHeader transactionId=tcm:0-277451-66560 control=COMMIT] to D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-277451-66560.COMMIT\transaction.xml
2012-12-05 05:50:44,793 DEBUG ZipWorker - Create Commit package for transacton: tcm:0-277451-66560 at D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-277451-66560.COMMIT.zip
2012-12-05 05:50:44,793 DEBUG TransactionHeader - Writing[TransactionHeader transactionId=tcm:0-277451-66560 control=ROLLBACK] to D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-277451-66560.ROLLBACK\transaction.xml
2012-12-05 05:50:44,793 DEBUG ZipWorker - Create Rollback package for transacton: tcm:0-277451-66560 at D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-277451-66560.ROLLBACK.zip
2012-12-05 05:50:44,809 DEBUG ZipWorker - Zipping has been completed for transaction: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:44,809 DEBUG StepPrepare - Zipping has been completed successfully for transaction: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:44,809 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2012-12-05 05:50:44,824 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2012-12-05 05:50:44,840 DEBUG DestinationController - Transports in progress: 1
2012-12-05 05:50:44,840 DEBUG ParallelDestinationWorker - Waiting for transport result for: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:44,840 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2012-12-05 05:50:44,840 DEBUG TransportSender - Starting sending transportPackage: D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-277451-66560.Content.zip
2012-12-05 05:50:45,074 DEBUG DestinationController - Checking destination for transport metadata
2012-12-05 05:50:45,074 INFO  TransportPoolManager - Creating a new TransportPoolConnector, because no available connectors in connection pool
2012-12-05 05:50:45,074 DEBUG TransportPoolConnector - Configuring TransportPoolConnector.
2012-12-05 05:50:45,074 DEBUG HTTPSTransportConnector - Authentication information supplied, setting basic credentials
2012-12-05 05:50:45,074 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.51.151:8082/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2012-12-05 05:50:45,074 DEBUG DestinationController - Starting polling on destination: bNZqVt3QAt1olhLc6Hdaqw==
2012-12-05 05:50:45,074 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2012-12-05 05:50:45,105 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.51.151:8082/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2012-12-05 05:50:45,105 DEBUG DestinationController - Polling attempt 1 for transaction: tcm:0-277451-66560 on destination: bNZqVt3QAt1olhLc6Hdaqw==
2012-12-05 05:50:45,277 DEBUG TransportService - Starting handing of a transaction
2012-12-05 05:50:45,277 INFO  TransportService - Starting transport handling of transaction: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:45,292 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2012-12-05 05:50:45,292 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2012-12-05 05:50:45,292 DEBUG DestinationProgressWorker - Starting retrieving active transactions at destination: bNZqVt3QAt1olhLc6Hdaqw==
2012-12-05 05:50:45,323 DEBUG DestinationProgressWorker - Found 0 transactions in progress and 0 waiting transactions.
2012-12-05 05:50:45,323 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.51.151:8082/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2012-12-05 05:50:45,323 INFO  DestinationController - Transaction fits inside current window, proceeding transaction: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:45,323 DEBUG TransactionManager - Destination is available for transport: bNZqVt3QAt1olhLc6Hdaqw==
2012-12-05 05:50:45,323 DEBUG TransactionManager - All destinations are available for transport of transaction: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:45,323 INFO  ZipWorker - Preparing TransportPackage for id: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:45,323 DEBUG ZipWorker - Zipping Transportpackage: c:\Temp\tcm_0-277451-66560.Content
2012-12-05 05:50:45,323 INFO  ZipWorker - Creating rollback and commit packages for transaction: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:45,323 DEBUG TransactionHeader - Writing[TransactionHeader transactionId=tcm:0-277451-66560 control=PREPARE] to D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-277451-66560.PREPARE\transaction.xml
2012-12-05 05:50:45,323 DEBUG ZipWorker - Create Prepare package for transacton: tcm:0-277451-66560 at D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-277451-66560.PREPARE.zip
2012-12-05 05:50:45,323 DEBUG TransactionHeader - Writing[TransactionHeader transactionId=tcm:0-277451-66560 control=COMMIT] to D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-277451-66560.COMMIT\transaction.xml
2012-12-05 05:50:45,339 DEBUG ZipWorker - Create Commit package for transacton: tcm:0-277451-66560 at D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-277451-66560.COMMIT.zip
2012-12-05 05:50:45,339 DEBUG TransactionHeader - Writing[TransactionHeader transactionId=tcm:0-277451-66560 control=ROLLBACK] to D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-277451-66560.ROLLBACK\transaction.xml
2012-12-05 05:50:45,339 DEBUG ZipWorker - Create Rollback package for transacton: tcm:0-277451-66560 at D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-277451-66560.ROLLBACK.zip
2012-12-05 05:50:45,339 DEBUG ZipWorker - Zipping has been completed for transaction: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:45,339 DEBUG StepPrepare - Zipping has been completed successfully for transaction: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:45,339 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2012-12-05 05:50:45,339 INFO  StepPhaseOneCommit - Handling transaction control (1st phase commit/rollback) for transaction: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:45,339 DEBUG TransactionControlWorker - Prepare for tcm:0-277451-66560 has failed on some destinations, scheduling rollback
2012-12-05 05:50:45,339 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2012-12-05 05:50:45,339 DEBUG DestinationController - Transports in progress: 2
2012-12-05 05:50:45,339 DEBUG ParallelDestinationWorker - Waiting for transport result for: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:45,355 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2012-12-05 05:50:45,355 DEBUG TransportSender - Starting sending transportPackage: D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-277451-66560.ROLLBACK.zip
2012-12-05 05:50:45,370 DEBUG HTTPSTransportConnector - Successfully transport content to destination: http://10.97.51.151:8082/httpupload.aspx
2012-12-05 05:50:45,370 DEBUG TransportSender - Sending D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-277451-66560.ROLLBACK.zip to destination: bNZqVt3QAt1olhLc6Hdaqw== completed.
2012-12-05 05:50:45,370 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.51.151:8082/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2012-12-05 05:50:45,370 DEBUG ParallelDestinationWorker - Received item from transport destination: bNZqVt3QAt1olhLc6Hdaqw==
2012-12-05 05:50:45,370 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2012-12-05 05:50:45,370 DEBUG DestinationController - Finalizing transport for transaction: tcm:0-277451-66560 on destination: bNZqVt3QAt1olhLc6Hdaqw==
2012-12-05 05:50:45,370 DEBUG DestinationController - Transports in progress: 2
2012-12-05 05:50:45,386 INFO  StepPhaseOneCommit - Transport was succesfully completed for transaction control: tcm:0-277451-66560
2012-12-05 05:50:45,386 INFO  StepPrepare - Finalizing/cleaning transaction: tcm:0-277451-66560
```

After this lot of polling related entires are there for transcation 277451

Comment: what happen if you try publish failed pages/components again?

Comment: Template type being used is not relevant.  2011 supports both VBScript and Compound Templates.  Also, I do not believe the # of renderers is relevant either.  Check the cd_transport log file in Tridion\logs.  Also, open the logback config file and make sure log level is debug.  Sounds like it could be a permissions or security issue.  Also, try accessing the https URL for the deployer from the CMS and see if it is not blocked.

Comment: Republising sometimes goes well but maximum time it fails, @robrtc yes httpupload.aspx is accessible from CMS server.  I didn't get your point Template type being used is not relevant.

Comment: Templates cause failure early in the process and the error is visible in the Event Viewer.  The fact you are using compound templates instead of VBScript templates does not have any impact on the ability to deploy those content items.  The errors you experience are clearly in the deployer, transport or storage.  Please post any log data you have in those logs.

Comment: Now while publishing itself we get error in CME, Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/2011/netTcp. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.0296000. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2660. Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/2011/netTcp. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.0296000. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2660.

Comment: after restart of services above mentioned issue is gone.

Comment: Log file is too big.. can't paste here..

Comment: Not whole log file - anything that looks unusual or with errors...I would also suggest to open a case with Tridion Customer support and follow a thorough debugging process...

Comment: Yeah, keep in mind that StackOverflow is a site for PROGRAMMING questions, not a customer support replacement.

Comment: Interresting question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Answer (score 4):

Today we faced the same issue -  to resolved this issue we have took following steps:
-Remove two jar files (**jaxb-api.jar** & **jaxb-impl.jar**) from \bin\config directory at content delivery server.
-Cross verify following JDBC connection related jar file in same directory

**sqljdbc4.jar** with slf4j-1.7.1.zip at same location.

Restart application related services/apache/tomacat etc..

By doing this we are able to solved above issue..
Hope this will solved your problem
Thanks ! Hiren